# Make a persistent copy of a tree (C++)

Tags: c++, tree, persist

I am thinking about using this STL-like tree library for C++ http://tree.phi-sci.com/ to store  hierarchical data (think organisation chart).

In my case the tree only contains the structure, the 'payload' of each node is stored elsewhere. So it will probably end up as a `tree<int>` or a `tree<simple_class_containing_a_couple_of_ints>`

I would like to find the best way to persist the tree. To be more specific I would like to find the best way to persist the tree to a SQL database so it can be loaded back into the application on startup.

So my question is: How can I persist a tree contained in a tree.hh container to a SQL database?

Note: It is not necessary to store it as a tree structure in the database (i.e. no need for nested set, adjacency list). There is no need to query the database as the whole tree will be loaded into memory.

UPDATE:

I have found this class as an alternative to tree.hh here: http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/ntree.html
I cannot comment yet on any performance differences, but it mostly implements what I need and has a persistence class (sorry no link as not enough reputation) that I can dump to a BLOB. I haven't entered this as an answer yet because I am still interested in any alternative solutions.

Comment: Hi. What is your question?

Comment: How can I persist the tree stored in a tree.hh container to a SQL database? Thanks - I have added this in the main text for clarity.

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL if there is no need to query the database???

Comment: Thanks, because I am already storing a lot of other things in the database and it will allow me to have a single portable file. One option would be to save the tree as a BLOB though.

Comment: How big could be your tree? A few thousand nodes or many millions?

Comment: A few thousand at most.

Answer (score 0):

I would persist each node in one SQL table (one row per node) and perhaps each node -> sibling relation in another table.
I am not sure SQL is the best way to persist. You could consider using JSON.

Comment: Thank you, this was also my thought. If the table had a column for node ID and a column for parent ID I can reconstruct the tree. But for each row I would have to 'find' the parent in the tree so I could append the child and this seems inefficient. Is there a better way?